# Run daemon as another user on mac os x

Tags: macos, unix, hudson, daemon, launchd

I'm trying right now to create separate user for jenkins on Mac Os and run it with this user.
I've created a new user:

```
# Create the group
sudo dscl . create /Groups/jenkins
sudo dscl . create /Groups/jenkins PrimaryGroupID 300
# Create the user
sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins
sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins PrimaryGroupID 300
sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins UniqueID 300
sudo dscl . create /Users/jenkins UserShell /bin/bash
# Set the users pasword
sudo dscl . passwd /Users/jenkins 123qweASD
# Add the user to the group
sudo dscl . append /Groups/jenkins GroupMembership jenkins
```

And the I try to run jenkins as jenkins user:

```
sudo su - jenkins -c run_jenkins.sh
```

and got an error:

```
su: no directory
```

after I created directory for jenkins user:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/jenkins NFSHomeDirectory /Users/jenkins
```

followed next error:

```
su: unknown login: jenkins
```

General quiestion:

1. How can I create an _www like user for a daemon, without home directory i.e.
2. How can I run a script as this new user.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are we talking about launchd type of daemons?

Comment: yes, i've plist for that. Wanted just test if it work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### man launchd.plist

```
 UserName <string>
 This optional key specifies the user to run the job as. This key is only
 applicable when launchd is running as root.

 GroupName <string>
 This optional key specifies the group to run the job as. This key is only
 applicable when launchd is running as root. If UserName is set and Group-
 Name is not, the the group will be set to the default group of the user.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the absolute of `run_jenkins.sh` (assuming its `/Users/jenkins/run_jenkins.sh`):

```
sudo su - jenkins -c /Users/jenkins/run_jenkins.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

`su -` emulates a normal login, and hence requires that the account be set up for regular logins (have a shell and home directory defined, etc).  Unless you need this for some reason, just let sudo do it:

```
sudo -u jenkins run_jenkins.sh
```