# What NSHomeDirectory returns for a daemon?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I am looking at disassembled code of iOS deamon (preinstalled) and I see that it uses `NSHomeDirectory()`.

I am wondering what is `NSHomeDirectory()` for it? A directory where binary is stored? or `/` or something else?

My guess is that jailbrake deamons should behave the same way as preinstalled deamons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, I think it's `/var/username`, where the username is the username that owns the daemon process.   Basically, this could be `/var/root`, or `/var/mobile` depending on which user you run as.

By default, I'm seeing my daemon process run as `root` and therefore show `/var/root` when I call `NSHomeDirectory()`.  However, if [I modify the daemon's plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8000327/119114) to include:

```xml
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>mobile</string>
```

Then the process runs as `mobile` and returns `/var/mobile` from a call to `NSHomeDirectory()`.

But, I'm not 100% sure that the *default* I see on my phone is universal, as it could depend on other factors (including how you build and install your daemon).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's /var/mobile