# Python script fails using launchd and Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, launchd, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to run a simple script using launchd in OS X 10.10.5 but the job fails. I think it has something to do with permissions/privileges not set correctly?

This is the error code it throws up:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/John/Documents/AutoRun/OpenTwitter.py", line 7, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0.b2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 64, in **init**
>       self.service = Service(executable_path, firefox_binary=self.options.binary_location)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0.b2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/service.py", line 44, in **init**
>       log_file = open(log_path, "a+")
>   IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
>   Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'log_file'" in `<bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x10ca6bdd0>>` ignored

I do get the printed "start script" in the console job.out that I've hardcoded into my script, so I assume launchd is actually starting the script ok, but it's running into a problem with Selenium/Firefox driver? And this is where my permissions issue is coming into play?

It runs fine in IDE/run and from the terminal.

Here's the test code I'm trying to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from selenium import webdriver

print("start script")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com/search?q=news&src=typd&lang=en")


print("twitter open, done")
```

The P.List as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>JohnsJob.job</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/John/Documents/AutoRun/OpenTwitter.py</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/JohnsJob.job.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/JohnsJob.job.out</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>10</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>14</integer>
            <key>Weekday</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note: I change the time for this code to run in launchd so I can test.

Comment: You are precisely correct; the lack of permissions are stopping your script from executing properly. I would suggest you also include the .plist for the launchd in your question too.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've added the p.list code to the original question, any idea why the permissions are not set correctly and/or how/what file to set them on?

Comment: Are you launching this as a launchagent or launchdaemon, and which directory is the .plist located?

Comment: It's located in /Users/John/Library/LaunchAgents - I think it's a "User Agent", that's what it tells me in launchd (I'm new to this so not sure if that's the correct answer)

Comment: These can be tough to get right the first time and might require trying a few different things. I would start in the .plist and maybe try changing `<key>Program</key><string>/Users/John/Documents/AutoRun/OpenTwitter.py</string>` to `<key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>python</string>
    <string>/Users/John/Documents/AutoRun/OpenTwitter.py</string>
  </array>`

Comment: Nope - didn't help, I couldn't reopen it in launchd after the edit either.

Comment: The main issue then is the launchagent needs to be able to use python like your normal user, so there are a couple other things in the plist you could try, see this example ... http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/93174/10139, or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8000327/499581

Comment: Thanks - I had a go and I think I changed the permissions but I don't think it's the script causing the issue, I think it's Selenium or the driver that doesn't have the correct permission within the script. **Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. ** & **Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" **

Comment: I tried creating an automator "watch me do" app to open the terminal and run the script - then run this from launchd, this also crashes.

Comment: Yes I think you are correct about that. So I guess the question is what user/group is set on that. You can browse into that directory and check. I'm guessing it's maybe root. I'm not sure if you could realistically set the user group to that in the plots once you find out, but perhaps worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it to work by putting the geckodriver in /usr/bin

1. Move the file to /usr/bin directory: sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin
2. Goto /usr/bin directory and you would need to run something like "chmod a+x geckodriver" to mark it executable.

I think it was having trouble finding the PATH to the driver and stopping the script dead.